# Process json with different data type in Circe

Tags: java, json, scala, circe

In my case, there might be different data type of same json field. Example:

```
"need_exp":1500
```

or

```
"need_exp":"-"
```

How to process this case? I know it can be processed by `parse` or use custom encoders, but this is a very complex json text, is there any way to solve that without rewriting the whole decoder (for example, just *"tell"* the decoder to convert all `Int` to `String` in `need_exp` field)?

Comment: With a custom decoder checking the `Json` kind

Comment: What about if the field was an `Option[Int]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to use a custom decoder. Rewrite a little part of the JSON can be fine.

For example, there is a simple JSON:

```
{  
   /*many fields*/
   "hotList":[/* ... many lists inside*/],
   "list":[ {/*... many fields*/
         "level_info":{  
            "current_exp":11463,
            "current_level":5,
            "current_min":10800,
            "next_exp":28800 //there is the problem
         },
         "sex":"\u4fdd\u5bc6"},/*...many lists*/]
}
```

In this case, I don't need to rewrite the whole JSON encoder, just write a custom encoder of `level_info`:

```
implicit val decodeUserLevel: Decoder[UserLevel] = (c: HCursor) => for
{
    current_exp <- c.downField("current_exp").as[Int]
    current_level <- c.downField("current_level").as[Int]
    current_min <- c.downField("current_min").as[Int]
    next_exp <- c.downField("next_exp").withFocus(_.mapString
    {
        case """-""" => "-1"
        case default => default
    }).as[Int]
} yield
{
    UserLevel(current_exp, current_level, current_min, next_exp)
}
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

It is called a disjunction which can be encoded with the Scala standard `Either` class. 
Simply map the json that to the following class:

```
case class Foo(need_exp: Either[String, Int])
```